# How to set the brightness of the screen on WP7

Tags: xna, silverlight-3.0, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

How to set the brightness of the screen on WP7 to its maximum using silverlight/xna?

```
<Canvas x:Name="light" Background="White" Width="480" Height="800" />
```

I used this code .Have any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the brightness from a 3rd party application. There's no public API for this.